# Can not Access my Own Web App on Test Deployment Menu

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, google-account

So for almost 6-12 months I've been developing my own Web App using Google App Script.
Everything was fine, New Deployment was okay, Test Deployment was okay.

Until just yesterday (and still happening today), when I was trying to test my app using Test Deployment menu, the page "Access Denied" appears, and it request for an access.

The problem is:

- I signed is as my self, Test Deployment-ing as myself, logged in to Chrome as my self, I am the owner of the file, and not signed in as another email.
- And yes, I tried to invoke "request permission" to my self, and no notification appeared in my email. I also tried to signin as another account I have. But all my efforts were futile.

NB:

- This problem occured when yesterday I tried to signed in as myself on my friend computer (No, i did not doing something like revoking my permission and give it to ohter etc, just plain sign in and try to Test Development on his PC).
- I can publish and access this web app with no problem. This problem only occured on Test Deployment only.

Any Idea how this could happened? Or any work around?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I Will try to answer my own Question

I'm not sure what I just did, but re-deploying my App and try to test deployment it, solve the problem.

PS:
I did this 2 times before, but the Drive still requesting access for Test Deployment. But not this time. Strange, still curious, but my problem Resolved.